# Квадратная спираль из строк рандомной длины и количества

Tags: php, алгоритм, строки, геометрия

Всем привет, застрял на этом пункте в одном тестовом задании.
Имея массив рандомных строк ( строки введенные пользователем)
нужно вывести на экран ( pre таг в помощь) квадратную спираль из этих строк

```
  --------------------------
  |                         |
  |    -----------------    |
  |    |                 |  |
  |    |                 |  |
  |    |                 |  |
  |    |                 |  |
  |     -----------      |  |
  |                      |  |
   --------------------- |  |
                            |
----------------------------
```

(начальная точка, ориентация и направление не важны).

Если есть несколько строк одинаковой длины, можно использовать тире вокруг них.

Желательно на php, но мне хотелось бы понять алгоритм

Comment: какой код уже есть у тебя?

Comment: никакого пока что

Comment: ну двумерный массив создай, потом поочередно проходи массив 4 циклами - горизонтально слева направо/вертикально снизу вверх/горизонтально справа налево/вертикально сверху вниз - до тех пор, пока следующая клетка непустая, как-то так мне видится.